# Google Tag manager for Android v4 container.close()

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I am curious how can I close container that I don't want to use anymore. I have seen [close()](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/Container.html#public-methods) method in version 3, but if i am not wrong, it has been removed, right? Why?

**Why do I need it?** Just becase I want to switch containers in runtime. Actualy I need to **serve multiple** GoogleAnalytics accouts/GoogleTagManager accounts (containers).

I have created wrapper around android TagManger which load container from web via its ID, and then push data to dataLayer of actual container. Then on demand can download another container and push its data and becase of bound between the container and GA, I can see info in GA.

But there are problems, **that there is no close() method, GTM is singleton and I don't have source code** to make it possible somehow. I know that same functionality is possible on iOS with same way that I have just described above.

The result of this is that I can see data on both GA accounts and that definitely is not what I want.

[image: GA one]

[image: GA two]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can release the current container before assign a new one

```
if (ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder() != null) {
    //release the old container
    ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().release();
   }
// assign the new container
ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
```